# trying to setup timescaledb-ha edition

Tags: timescaledb

I'm trying to setup timescaledb high availability edition with the following command on a aws ubuntu instance... However, I got this error... could anyone help?

```
(base) ubuntu@ip-321-12-32-154:~$ sudo docker run -ti --user 1000:1000 --volume=/tmp/vmount:/home/postgresql/pgdata --rm -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=sdafasd -e PGDATA=/home/postgresql/pgdata timescale/timescaledb-ha:pg13-latest
chmod: changing permissions of '/home/postgresql/pgdata': Operation not permitted
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "C.UTF-8".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are disabled.

fixing permissions on existing directory /home/postgresql/pgdata ... initdb: error: could not change permissions of directory "/home/postgresql/pgdata": Operation not permitted
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if it is still relevant, but I had a similar issue and hope it will help others.

The main issue here is the `postgres` is **NOT** the owner of the `/home/postgresql/pgdata` in your case. The UID needs to be matched according to Postgres. https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres

> The main caveat to note is that postgres doesn't care what UID it runs as (as long as the owner of /var/lib/postgresql/data matches)

When you do bind-mounting a directory from host to container, the permission of the file and directory is maintained. I assume the `vmount` doesn't exist in `/tmp` when you do the docker run and docker will create the `/tmp/vmount` owned by root. This is why you see the error as `postgres` doesn't own the directory.

Options to avoid:

1. If the UID of `ubuntu` is also 1000 (same as the `postgres` user in the container), create the `/tmp/vmount` first or use another directory owned by `ubuntu` and then bring up the container.

```
mkdir /tmp/vmount
sudo docker run -ti --volume=/tmp/vmount:/home/postgresql/pgdata --rm -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=sdafasd -e PGDATA=/home/postgresql/pgdata timescale/timescaledb-ha:pg14-latest
```

2. Create a named volume and mount it to some directories that already exist inside the container and owned by `postgres`, like `/home/postgres/pgdata` or `/var/lib/postgresql`. **Note**, if you mount the volume to none pre-existed directory inside the container, docker will create the directory owned by root and cause the issue again.

```
docker volume create pgdata
sudo docker run -ti  --volume=pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql --rm -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=sdafasd -e PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql timescale/timescaledb-ha:pg14-latest

or

sudo docker run -ti --volume=pgdata:/home/postgres/pgdata --rm -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=sdafasd timescale/timescaledb-ha:pg14-latest
```

P.S. Looks like the default pgdata directory for `timescale/timescaledb-ha` is `/home/postgres/pgdata` which is different to `timescale/timescaledb` image under `/var/lib/postgresql/data`

Following the [TSDB doc](https://docs.timescale.com/install/latest/installation-docker/) for `timescale/timescaledb-ha` might cause this issue as well.